# Help adding threading for GUI progress

Tags: python, multithreading, ftp

I have an FTP function that traces the progress of running upload but my understanding of threading is limited and i have been unable to implement a working solution... I'd like to add a GUI progress bar to my current Application by using threading. Can someone show me a basic function using asynchronous threads that can be updated from another running thread?

```
def ftpUploader():
    BLOCKSIZE = 57344 # size 56 kB

    ftp = ftplib.FTP()
    ftp.connect(host)
    ftp.login(login, passwd)
    ftp.voidcmd("TYPE I")
    f = open(zipname, 'rb')
    datasock, esize = ftp.ntransfercmd(
        'STOR %s' % os.path.basename(zipname))
    size = os.stat(zipname)[6]
    bytes_so_far = 0
    print 'started'
    while 1:
        buf = f.read(BLOCKSIZE)
        if not buf:
            break
        datasock.sendall(buf)
        bytes_so_far += len(buf)
        print "\rSent %d of %d bytes %.1f%%\r" % (
              bytes_so_far, size, 100 * bytes_so_far / size)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    datasock.close()
    f.close()
    ftp.voidresp()
    ftp.quit()
    print 'Complete...'
```

Comment: Do not use the GUI from the new thread. Reserve all your GUI operations for a single thread, and let the second thread do the FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick overview of threading, just in case :) I won't go into too much detail into the GUI stuff, other than to say that you should check out wxWidgets. Whenever you do something that takes a long time, like:

```
from time import sleep
for i in range(5):
    sleep(10)
```

You'll notice that to the user, the entire block of code seems to take 50 seconds. In those 5 seconds, your application can't do anything like update the interface, and so it looks like it's frozen. To solve this problem, we use threading.

Usually there are two parts to this problem; the overall set of things you want to process, and the operation that takes a while, that we'd like to chop up. In this case, the overall set is the for loop and the operation we want chopped up is the sleep(10) function.

Here's a quick template for the threading code, based on our previous example. You should be able to work your code into this example.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

# Threading.
# The amount of seconds to wait before checking for an unpause condition.
# Sleeping is necessary because if we don't, we'll block the os and make the
# program look like it's frozen.
PAUSE_SLEEP = 5

# The number of iterations we want.
TOTAL_ITERATIONS = 5

class myThread(Thread):
    '''
    A thread used to do some stuff.
    '''
    def __init__(self, gui, otherStuff):
        '''
        Constructor. We pass in a reference to the GUI object we want
        to update here, as well as any other variables we want this
        thread to be aware of.
        '''
        # Construct the parent instance.
        Thread.__init__(self)

        # Store the gui, so that we can update it later.
        self.gui = gui

        # Store any other variables we want this thread to have access to.
        self.myStuff = otherStuff

        # Tracks the paused and stopped states of the thread.
        self.isPaused = False
        self.isStopped = False

    def pause(self):
        '''
        Called to pause the thread.
        '''
        self.isPaused = True

    def unpause(self):
        '''
        Called to unpause the thread.
        '''
        self.isPaused = False

    def stop(self):
        '''
        Called to stop the thread.
        '''
        self.isStopped = True

    def run(self):
        '''
        The main thread code.
        '''
        # The current iteration.
        currentIteration = 0

        # Keep going if the job is active.
        while self.isStopped == False:
            try:
                # Check for a pause.
                if self.isPaused:
                    # Sleep to let the os schedule other tasks.
                    sleep(PAUSE_SLEEP)
                    # Continue with the loop.
                    continue

                # Check to see if we're still processing the set of
                # things we want to do.
                if currentIteration < TOTAL_ITERATIONS:
                    # Do the individual thing we want to do.
                    sleep(10)
                    # Update the count.
                    currentIteration += 1
                    # Update the gui.
                    self.gui.update(currentIteration,TOTAL_ITERATIONS)
                else:
                    # Stop the loop.
                    self.isStopped = True

            except Exception as exception:
                # If anything bad happens, report the error. It won't
                # get written to stderr.
                print exception
                # Stop the loop.
                self.isStopped = True

        # Tell the gui we're done.
        self.gui.stop()
```

To call this thread, all you have to do is:

```
aThread = myThread(myGui,myOtherStuff)
aThread.start()
```

Comment: I was able to insert and run my code using the example provided but Im still not sure how to update the main window... How to do i pass back the status to the original GUI instance? BTY: Im using wxPython..

Comment: When you construct your thread, pass the window as a parameter to the thread and store the window locally. That's self.gui. Then when you're done, you can call a method on the main thread to update it.